# Translate JAGS != logical operator into Stan

Tags: r, jags, stan

I am trying to adapt some of Kruschke's code into Stan and cannot reproduce the following.

```
# JAGS code
for ( i in 1:NxBetweenLvl ) { 
     for ( j in 1:NxWithinLvl ) { 
         mBxW[i,j] <- ( sum( mSxBxW[1:NxSubjectLvl,i,j] ) / sum( mSxBxW[1:NxSubjectLvl,i,j]!=0 ) )
     }
}
```

Note that `mSxBxW[,,]` is a three-dimentional array defined upstream.

What does the function in the loop do? Is it "sum of cells `1:NxSubectLvl` in dimensions `i` and `j` in array `mSxBxW[,,]` divided by sum of the total *number* of non-zero cells across cells `1:NxSubectLvl`in dimension `i` and `j`? Is that right?

And how would i reproduce this in Stan?

If I use this code in the same place in my Stan script...

```
// Stan Code
      for (i in 1:nGroup) {
        for (j in 1:nCond) {
          mGxC[i,j] = sum(mSxCxG[1:nSubj,i,j]) / sum( mSxCxG[1:nSubj,i,j]!=0 );
        }
      }
```

... it throws the error

```
Binary infix operator != with functional interpretation logical_neq requires arguments or primitive type (int or real), found left type=real[], right arg type=int;
```

Which means nothing to me, other than there is something about the `!=` operator that works in JAGS but not in Stan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the 0 is an integer while your matrix has reals in it.

One way around this is to just define a real variable as zero and use that:

```
   {
      real zero = 0;
      for (i in 1:nGroup) {
        for (j in 1:nCond) {
          mGxC[i,j] = sum(mSxCxG[1:nSubj,i,j]) / sum( mSxCxG[1:nSubj,i,j]!=zero);
        }
      }
   }
```